# Trouble filling a dynamic c array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having issues with filling an array of strings that was created dynamically. The array basically contains two strings and I would like to print them both with their lengths. I am getting a very weird result whereby the memory locations are getting mixed up. Please see the code below.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

```
void printWords(char **words, int numberOfWords)
{ 
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < numberOfWords; index++)
    {
        printf("%s, %d\n", &(*words)[index], (int)strlen(&(*words)[index]));        
    }
}


void fillWords(char **words)
{
    *words = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));

    char hello[] = {"Hello"};
    (*words)[0] = (char)malloc(strlen(hello) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&(*words)[0], hello); //Copy word into array 

    char world[] = {"Worldz"};
    (*words)[1] = (char)malloc(strlen(world) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&(*words)[1], world); //Copy word into array 
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *words;

    fillWords(&words);
    printWords(&words, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be

```
Hello, 5
Worldz, 6
```

however I am getting

```
HWorldz, 7
Worldz, 6
```

Comment: Homework? No problem if it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between `char *` and `char **`.

Also, be sure to allocate enough memory for the null-termination character at the end of the string.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void printWords(char **words, int numberOfWords)
{ 
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < numberOfWords; index++)
    {
        printf("%s, %d\n", words[index], (int)strlen(words[index]));        
    }
}

char ** createWords()
{
    char ** words;

    // Allocate memory for an array of pointers, length 2.
    words = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));

    char hello[] = {"Hello"};
    words[0] = malloc((strlen(hello)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[0], hello); //Copy word into array 

    char world[] = {"Worldz"};
    words[1] = malloc((strlen(world)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[1], world); //Copy word into array 

    return words;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char **words;

    words = createWords();
    printWords(words, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I renamed fillWords to createWords and made it return a pointer instead of taking a pointer as an argument.  If you really want fillWords to take a pointer as an argument, you can do it, but the argument will have to be of type `char ***`.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: you can't put 2 words in a `char *` *(well ... you can, but not the way you're doing; and the way to do it is nothing like your code)*.

You need an "array of strings", or, more C-like, an array of `char *`:

```
char *words[2]; /* words[0] and words[1] are pointers to char */
char *wrong;    /* wrong[0] is a char; wrong[1] is a char */
```

So, change the definition of `words` in your main and check/edit all the other functions for correctness.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *words[2];

    fillWords(words);
    printWords(words, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want a pointer to a char. I want an array of chars. I think I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to end up with a single string with "Hello\x00Worldz": I mean with embedded null terminators?

Comment: No, my intention is to create a dynamic char array. Each index of the array contains a string. Please see my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I was getting confused between char* and char. What I want was an array of chars.

```
void printWords(char **words, int numberOfWords)
{ 
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < numberOfWords; index++)
    {
        printf("%s, %d\n", words[index], (int)strlen(words[index]));        
    }
}


void fillWords(char **words)
{
    *words = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));

    char hello[] = {"Hello"};
    words[0] = malloc(strlen(hello) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[0], hello); //Copy word into array 

    char world[] = {"Worldz"};
    words[1] = malloc(strlen(world) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[1], world); //Copy word into array 
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *words;

    fillWords(&words);
    printWords(&words, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just ran it and got the right output with no errors. You didn't provide an answer.

Comment: Hmm ... sorry, I misread it. Only 1 important error: To hold the string "Hello" you need 6 bytes (remember the null terminator), but you're only allocating 5 with `malloc(strlen(hello) * sizeof(char))`.

Comment: Sorry David... this code does compile (after include stdio.h, string.h, and malloc.h) and it does give the right output, but I think that might just be luck.  Assigning to `*word` should be the same as assigning to `word[0]`, which means that your first malloc statement is not doing anything useful.  I removed your first malloc statement and the result was the same!  This means you are doing it wrong.  I'm working on an answer.

Comment: @pmg. It would be help if you could contribute (i.e. provide a meaningful answer) rather than just tell me I'm wrong.

Comment: I told you why it's wrong: treating a `char**` as `char*`. I provided you with another approach: my answer with `char *words[2];`. I asked if you really wanted yet another approach with embedded null terminators. I can write the program (either of the two valid answers) and post the answer here, but then you wouldn't do any mistakes of your own ... and you don't learn from /MY/ mistakes.